# how to print a javafx node when using RTL languages

Tags: javafx, printing, orientation, direction, persian

I am developing a JavaFX app which is supporting [Persian language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_language). As some of you may know letters in Persian language is written from right to left just like Hebrew or Arabic. Using [NodeOrientation](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Node+Orientation+in+JavaFX) it is fairly easy to put Persian content in the right order on the window, BUT the problem arises when I try to print a JavaFX Node, the result printed paper is reversed. I try to explain the problem by showing you the content when they appear correctly on the window but incorrectly on the printed media.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found nasty a workaround which I try to explain:

```
val pj = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob()
val pl = pj.printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.HARDWARE_MINIMUM)
pj.jobSettings.pageLayout = pl
if(pj.showPrintDialog(stage)) {
    val rotate = Transform.rotate(90.0, documentRoot.width/2, documentRoot.height/2)
    val affine = Transform.affine(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    documentRoot.transforms.add(rotate)
    documentRoot.transforms.add(affine)
    pj.printPage(documentRoot)
    pj.endJob()
    stage.hide()
  }
```

the trick is that you can rotate the node on the flay and apply the affine function on the node to make the being drawn in revered mode and the submit it to printer, the reversed form of a reversed node is correct as a result